# Script timeout for getText() on Ionic Title

Tags: ionic-framework, protractor

The following code results in a script timeout

```
return element(by.css(`${this.tag} ion-title`)).getText();
```

the html I am trying to read/test is the following

```
<ion-title _ngcontent-mrq-c137="" class="md title-default hydrated"> Welcome theeisbaer </ion-title>
```

The exact error is:

```
Failed: script timeout
        (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.116)
        (Driver info: chromedriver=80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18363 x86_64)#
```

What is causing this issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: you need to do something with that `.getText()`. That returns a promise that needs to be resolved. Also have you tried locating the element like this: `by.css('.md.title-default.hydrated')`

Comment: The return gets used in this piece of code: 
`expect(homePage.getTitle()).toContain('theeisbaer');` no haven't tried that yet, will do and update accordingly

The different selector made no difference. But I noticed something on the SUT, the timeout comes from "waitingForAngular" not the getText() because the app is still doing a GET request...